# Code compiles fine on GCC but loads of error on VC2010

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors, visual-c++

I made a number guessing game in C that compiles fine with GCC 4.7.1. But it gives a lot of error with VC2010. Mostly syntax error issues. I don't know why it gives these errors as I've compiled many other C sources with VC2010 without these errors.

I compile it with VC (Command Line) with the command: `cl guessgame.c`

VC gives the following errors:

```
Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 16.00.30319.01 for
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

guessgame.c
guessgame.c(8) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'
guessgame.c(9) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'
guessgame.c(10) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'
guessgame.c(11) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'
guessgame.c(12) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'
guessgame.c(13) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'
guessgame.c(14) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'
guessgame.c(20) : error C2065: 'chances' : undeclared identifier
guessgame.c(21) : error C2065: 'randRangeX' : undeclared identifier
guessgame.c(21) : error C2065: 'randRangeY' : undeclared identifier
guessgame.c(23) : error C2065: 'i' : undeclared identifier
guessgame.c(23) : error C2065: 'chances' : undeclared identifier
guessgame.c(23) : error C2065: 'i' : undeclared identifier
guessgame.c(23) : error C2065: 'i' : undeclared identifier
guessgame.c(25) : error C2065: 'chances' : undeclared identifier
guessgame.c(25) : error C2065: 'i' : undeclared identifier
guessgame.c(26) : error C2065: 'userAns' : undeclared identifier
guessgame.c(28) : error C2065: 'userAns' : undeclared identifier
guessgame.c(28) : error C2065: 'randomNumber' : undeclared identifier
guessgame.c(30) : error C2065: 'chances' : undeclared identifier
guessgame.c(30) : error C2065: 'i' : undeclared identifier
guessgame.c(36) : error C2065: 'wrong_guesses' : undeclared identifier
guessgame.c(39) : error C2065: 'wrong_guesses' : undeclared identifier
guessgame.c(41) : error C2065: 'randomNumber' : undeclared identifier
```

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int randomNumber = (rand() % 245)+5;
    int userAns;
    int randRangeX = randomNumber-((rand() % 3)+5);
    int randRangeY = randomNumber+((rand() % 3)+5);
    int chances = 3;
    int wrong_guesses = 0;
    int i;

    printf("Number guessing game v1.1.\n");
    printf("Copyright(c) 2013 - Ahnaf Tahmid.\n");
    printf("-----------------------------------\n\n");
    printf("Rules: 1) Guess the number.\n");
    printf("       2) You have %d chances.\n\n", chances);
    printf("The number is between %d and %d.", randRangeX, randRangeY);

    for(i = chances; i >= 1; i--)
    {
        printf("\nGuess %d: ", (chances-i)+1);
        scanf("%d", &userAns);
        while(getchar() != '\n');
        if(userAns == randomNumber)
        {
            printf("\nGood guess! You guessed it in %d turn(s).\n", (chances-i)+1);
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Aww, bad guess.\n");
            wrong_guesses += 1;
        }
    }
    if(wrong_guesses == 3)
    {
        printf("\nGame Over!\n\nThe answer was %d.\n", randomNumber);
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which is line 8 in your source code?

Comment: @verbose: int randomNumber = (rand() % 245)+5;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VC2010 supports C89 which requires that variables be declared at the start of their scope block.  You can build with both compilers if you move the `srand` call after your variable declarations and delay initialising the variables which depend on `rand()`.

```
int main()
{
    int randomNumber;
    int userAns;
    int randRangeX;
    int randRangeY;
    int chances = 3;
    int wrong_guesses = 0;
    int i;
    srand(time(NULL));
    randomNumber = (rand() % 245)+5;
    randRangeX = randomNumber-((rand() % 3)+5);
    randRangeY = randomNumber+((rand() % 3)+5);
```

Comment: But wouldn't that cause the program to not give correct random numbers since the random seed should be declared before calling rand()?

Comment: Yes, I've just edited to address this.  Looks like our posts overlapped.

Answer (score 2):

In C89, all variables have to be declared in the beginning of a block. This has been removed in C99.

But VC2010 doesn't support C99. So you have to put

```
srand(time(NULL));
```

after all the declaration of variables.

---

Reference:

> **C89 §3.6.2 Compound statement, or block**
>
> Syntax
>
> *compound-statement*:
>
> { declaration-list opt statement-list opt }
>
> *declaration-list*:
>
> declaration
>
> declaration-list declaration
>
> *statement-list*:
>
> statement
>
> statement-list statement

Note that in C89, declaration-list has to be before statement -list in a block.

> **C99 §6.8.2 Compound statement**
>
> Syntax
>
> *compound-statement*:
>
> { block-item-list_opt }
>
> *block-item-list:*
>
> block-item
>
> block-item-list block-item
>
> *block-item:*
>
> declaration
>
> statement

In C99, declaration and statement can be mixed.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach to solve the issue pointed out by the other answers would be to open a new scope:

```
int main()
{
  srand(time(NULL));

  {
    int randomNumber = (rand() % 245)+5;
    int userAns;
    int randRangeX = randomNumber-((rand() % 3)+5);
    int randRangeY = randomNumber+((rand() % 3)+5);
    int chances = 3;
    int wrong_guesses = 0;
    int i;
    ...
```